# Prevent MS-Word application from running auto macro when opening a Word document

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a code in my excel file which opens a certain Word document to read data from, and that Word document also has an "Document_Open" event handler (Which Shows a UserForm every time I open that Word document).

My Problem is that every time I run my Excel code to open up that Word file due to that "Document_Open" event handler, control of the code stuck in Word environment.

My code so far:

```
Private Sub CommandButton18_Click()

Dim Word As New Word.Application
Dim MRpt As Word.Document

Word.Visible = True
Set MRpt = Documents.Open(Filename:="MyWordDocumentPath" &".docm")

'At This Point code will be stuck because my UserForm inside my Word 
'document would show up and it prevents the code in Excel to continue)

End Sub
```

Comment: Try adding `Word.WordBasic.DisableAutoMacros 1` before you open the file to disable auto macro from running and `Word.WordBasic.DisableAutoMacros 0` after that to re-enable it. https://wordmvp.com/FAQs/InterDev/DisableAutoMacros.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the article in https://wordmvp.com/FAQs/InterDev/DisableAutoMacros.htm, you can disable/enable auto macro by using `WordBasic.DisableAutoMacros`:

```
Private Sub CommandButton18_Click()
   Dim Word As New Word.Application
   Dim MRpt As Word.Document

   Word.Visible = True
   Word.WordBasic.DisableAutoMacros 1 'Disable
   Set MRpt = Documents.Open(Filename:="MyWordDocumentPath" &".docm")

   'At This Point code will be stuck because my UserForm inside my Word 
   'document would show up and it prevents the code in Excel to continue)

   Word.WordBasic.DisableAutoMacros 0 'Enable back
End Sub
```